# Regular expression is not accepted

Tags: java, regex

I have implemented the code to count the occurrence of words in a text. However, my regular expression is not accepted for some reason and I get the following error: 
    `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character    class near index 12`

My code is:

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class CountOccurrenceOfWords {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    char lf = '\n';

String text = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times," + 
lf +
"it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness," + 
lf +
"it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity," + 
lf +
"it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness," + 
lf +
"it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair," + 
lf +
"we had everything before us, we had nothing before us," + 
lf +
"we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct" + 
lf +
"the other way--in short, the period was so far like the present" + 
lf +
"period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its" + 
lf +
"being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree" + 
lf +
"of comparison only." + 
lf +
"There were a king with a large jaw and a queen with a plain face," + 
lf +
"on the throne of England; there were a king with a large jaw and" + 
lf +
"a queen with a fair face, on the throne of France.  In both" + 
lf +
"countries it was clearer than crystal to the lords of the State" + 
lf +
"preserves of loaves and fishes, that things in general were" + 
lf +
"settled for ever";

    TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] words = text.split("[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        String key = words[i].toLowerCase();

        if(key.length() > 0) {
            if(map.get(key) == null){
                map.put(key, 1);
            }
            else{
                int value = map.get(key);
                value++;
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

    //Get key and value from each entry
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: entrySet){
        System.out.println(entry.getValue() + "\t" + entry.getKey());
    }
    }
}
```

Also, could you please provide a hint on how can I order the words alphabetically? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try and escape the brackets, the questionmark and the dot. => `\[\n\t\r\.,;:!\?\(\){`

Comment: Isn't the compiler error clear enough? You haven't closed the character class in your regex. `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){"` should be `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. i just had to replace `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){"` with `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){]"`. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `"]"` at end of your Regular Expression.

`"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){"`  is not correct.

You need to replace your Regular Expression to `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){]"`

Comment: Worked perfectly with that. Thank you very much. Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters for regular expressions. In your case you have not escaped `(`, `)`,`[`, `?`, `.` and `{`. Escape them using `\`. E.g. `\[`. You may also consider a predefined chracter class for whitespaces `\s` - this will match `\r`, `\t` and many more.

Comment: Thank you.. i just had to replace `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){"` with `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){]"`. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is an unclosed character class in your regular expression. RegEx has some 'pre-defined' characters wich you need to escape when looking for them.

A character class is:

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets.
>   [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

This means you have to either escape these characters:

```
\[\n\t\r\.,;:!\?\(\){
```

Or close the character class

```
[\n\t\r\.,;:!\?\(\){]
```

Either way you need to escape the dot, the question mark and the parentheses.

Comment: There is no need to escape metacharacters other then the closing square bracket within a character class.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. i just had to replace `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){"` with `"[\n\t\r.,;:!?(){]"`. Cheers